# Are Vue 3 class bindings with variables required to be in-line?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Given the following HTML:

```html
<template v-for="(child, index) in group">
    <div :class="{'border-pink-700 bg-gray-100 ': selected === child.id}">
        <div>Container Content</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a way to move the class binding out of the HTML, given that it relies on a condition passed via the `v-for` loop (`child.id`)?

The docs mention being able to [bind computed properties](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax), but my understanding is that these don't accept arguments (and I haven't been able to get it to work that way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a method and pass the item to the method:

```html
<div :class="classes(child)">
```

```js
setup() {
  ...
  const classes = (child) => {
    return {
      'border-pink-700 bg-gray-100': selected.value === child.id
    }
  } 
    
  return {
    ...
    selected,
    classes
  }
}
```

If you were using Vue 2 or the Options API:

```js
methods: {
  classes(child) {
    return {
      'border-pink-700 bg-gray-100': this.selected === child.id
    }
  }
}
```

Be sure to avoid changing instance properties in the method, but reading is ok.